# How can I obtain current Shell Content Page reference in Xamarin App Shell?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am developing a Xamarin Forms app using App Shell.

I found that I had to handle android hardware back button in AppShell.xaml.cs for a ShellContent Page, instead of ShellContent Page.

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{
  //Get currernt shell content and call its method
  //like (Shell.Current.Content as MyContentPage).MyMethod();
}
```

1)  How can I obtain current Shell Content Page reference in AppShell.xaml.cs?

2)  How can I change current Shell Content Page programmatically without routing ?

Best regards.

Comment: You can use MessaginCenter to call MyMethod() https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center

Comment: Why exactly do you need to know which ContentPage is being displayed?

Comment: I also see you want to call MyMethod, it would help if I knew what it did!

Comment: I added a Content Page which has a WebView control. When I press android hardware button, OnBackButtonPressed is called in AppShell.xaml.cs, not the Content Page. I want to call WebViewControl.GoBack method when android back button is pressed, not close my app.

Because OnBackButtonPressed is called in AppShell.xaml.cs, I have to get the current ShellContent instance and get WebViewControl and call its GoBack method.

Comment: Have you resolved this question?

Comment: @Jessie Zhang I implemented hardware back button handling with MessageCenter, but I could not find the actual answer of my questions.

Comment: Could you please post a basic demo so that others could help you better?

Answer (score 18):

It took quite a bit of digging, but I found a public Shell interface that meets this need. If you cast your `ShellSection` as an `IShellSectionController` you can use the `PresentedPage` property get the current `Page` object. Below is a code snippet, YMMV.

```
(Shell.Current?.CurrentItem?.CurrentItem as IShellSectionController)?.PresentedPage
```

Comment: Finally! I spent some time looking for this solution.. thank you very much

Answer (score 8):

I know this is a bit of a late answer, but I noticed that now there is a simpler solution than the solutions presented at the moment:

```
Shell.Current?.CurrentPage;
```

Comment: Simple and worked. I just did -
                    string currentPageTitle = Shell.Current?.CurrentPage.Title;

                   if (currentPageTitle != "Rewards")
                    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("ViewRewardsPage");

Answer (score 2):

In my case,I had bottom tabs with shell and wanted to get values from a tab when on a different tab, I modified @Nick W answer to achieve that using:

```cs
(Shell.Current.CurrentItem.Items[0] as IShellSectionController).PresentedPage
```

where index 0 refers to the first page in the Tabbar collection.