# Refresh Page with new data from APi by searchHandler Xamarin C#

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a question about the function search Handler in xamarin. I am just starting to learn xamarin, and I am trying in my project with search handler in xamarin to refresh my page with new data from the API. Currently, I am already lucky to retrieve the data, but when I do this, it creates a new page so to speak, but this is not what I want. He would kind of reload the page with new data. I have also already tried to delete previous page with "Shell.Current.Navigation.PopAsync();" But with no residual result. Anyone knows how I can achieve what I want? In addition, I would also like to remove that blur you get after the search. Thanks in advance!

```
using Eindproject.Models;
using Eindproject.Repository;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace Eindproject.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class Weather : ContentPage
    {
        private string icao = "EBBR";


        public Weather()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public Weather(string icao)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.icao = icao;
            frontend(icao);
        }

        public async void frontend(string par_icao)
        {
            // Get weather
            Models.WeatherModel weather = await DataRepository.GetWeatherAsync(par_icao);
            // Set data to labels
            lblLocation.Text = weather.Station.Name;
            lblCode.Text = weather.Code;
            lblTemp.Text = weather.Temperature.C.ToString();
            lblHumidity.Text = weather.Humidity.Percent.ToString();
            lblWind.Text = weather.Wind.Degrees.ToString();
            lblPressure.Text = weather.Presure.Hpa.ToString();
            lblDate.Text = weather.Date.ToString("G");
            lblMetar.Text = weather.Metar;
            lblCloud.Text = weather.Clouds[0].text;

            // Get sunrise and sunset
            SunTimes sunrise = await DataRepository.GetSunTimesAsync("EHBK");

            // Set data to labels
            lblSunrise.Text = sunrise.Sunrise.ToString("G");
            lblSunset.Text = sunrise.Sunset.ToString("G");

        }

        private void ToolbarItem_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

    }

    public class CustomSearchHandler : SearchHandler
    {
        // When user press enter and confirm get the icao code and search for the weather
        protected override void OnQueryConfirmed()
        {
            // Get the icao code
            string icao = Query;

            // Call wheather object
            Weather weather = new Weather();

            // Call frontend
            weather.frontend(icao);

        }
    }

}
```

[image: Exaple]

[image]

Comment: you need to update your page instead of navigating to a new instance of the page

Comment: if you need more specific advice, please [edit] your question to include the code that shows how you load your data the first time

Comment: @Jason I updated the question with where I load data for the first time.

Comment: your `frontend` method does all the necessary work, so you should just be able to call that again from the search handler

Comment: @Jason I just tried this, but this doesn't seem to work. I have dubbed and it comes up in the frontend function, but it does not populate any data. I get that blur screen, but without upgraded data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is creating a **new instance** of `Weather` and calling its `frontend` method.  That won't do anything useful.

```
Weather weather = new Weather();
weather.frontend(icao);
```

Instead you need to use the **existing instance** that is already displayed to the user

there are many ways to do this, but this might be the simplest

```
// get the current page
var page = App.Current.MainPage;
// cast it to the correct type
var weather = (Weather)page;
// call its frontend method
page.frontend(icao);
```

Comment: I just tried this, and I get the error   `System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'` on the cast of page. Page is of type `{xxx.AppShell}` any idea how I fix this then?

Comment: if you are using Shell, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57803149/how-can-i-obtain-current-shell-content-page-reference-in-xamarin-app-shell